# MS Teams : Post reply to MessageID

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

We want to post reply either using HttpPost API or Curl command to specific message(in a channel)  in ms teams(remotely). What is the best practice to do ? We used power automate to post the payload from ms teams to one of the server using HTTP Post,now -  we want one of the server to post reply to one of the message in  the channel in MS Teams.

Please confirm the best way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use Microsoft Graph API - [Send replies to a message in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post-replies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). In order to call this API you will need Application Access Token(See this to [*Get access without a user(Application permission)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta))

You can also use Bot Framework REST API -

[Create a bot with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) follow this to learn how to get access token and use API.

The API for your scenario is [Reply to activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#reply-to-activity)

For this you need to have a bot installed in the channel.